# How to allow my wife to stay in Poland for more than 90 days

Tags: poland, paperwork, polish-citizens

I am spending summer in Poland and I bought a return ticket that will make me come back after a 90-day period (I will be in the country for 92 days). I wonder how I can get some paperwork that will allow my wife to stay in the country for more than 90 days. I do not want to leave the country as I do not have much time and I would rather get some papers that would allow her to stay.

I would like a permanent solution so I can come back for longer stays to Poland with her over other journeys and vacations. (Since I travel to Europe a lot, a solution that would allow me to travel across other European nations for over 90 days as well would be preferred)

Comment: So is this more an immigration than a travel question?

Comment: no i made a mistake of asking about immigration on my last question. However all i really want is to come for long vacation to Poland with my wife. Not to migrate to live in Poland.

Comment: What country are you from?

Comment: I was born in Poland but I live in US (and thats where im visiting from)

Answer (score 4):

This may be interesting for you: http://www.nomadicmatt.com/travel-blogs/how-to-legally-stay-in-europe-for-more-than-90-days/:

> With so many visa rules, it’s so easy stay in Europe beyond 90 days as
>   a tourist – you just need to mix up the countries you visit. The
>   United Kingdom has their own rules that allow you to stay 180 days.
>   Most non-Schengen countries such as Ukraine, Moldova, Croatia, and
>   other Balkan countries allow you to stay for up to 60 or 90 days. So
>   all you need to do is spend 90 days in the Schengen zone, visit the
>   UK, go to the Balkans, hang out in Ukraine, or drink wine in Moldova.
>   If you align your schedule right, you can easily be out of the zone
>   for 90 days but still in Europe

Comment: A nice idea. It's only 2 days overtime, which can be spent, for example, in Lviv. A nice city near the Polish border.